# Likewise fails to create Home Directory in RedHat 6

Tags: redhat, likewise-open

It could be that I am missing something simple. But I can’t determine why users authenticated via AD are not getting home directories. I’ve looked at the documentation and tried to discover an error log but can’t find anything. Here is what I know.

OS: RedHat 6 
Software: Likewise 6.0 (RPM Install)
Successfully bound to an Active Directory domain… authentication via console and SSH works.

However when I login via the domain no home directory is created and subsequently BASH doesn’t have a profile:

```
-sh-4.1$
```

Looking at some variables via lwconfig it appears to be setup properly.

```
]# ./lwconfig --show CreateHomeDir 
boolean 
true 
local policy

# ./lwconfig --show HomeDirPrefix 
string 
/home 
local policy
```

Thoughts? Happy to provide further information but can’t find anything telling in /var/log/messages or other sources.

As part of troubleshooting this. Does anyone know if the home directory is checked/created on each login of a user or only first? If it occurs only on first login how can I reset/remove a user so it will attempt this process again?

Per Madden's comment:
There needs to be a sub 'likewise-open' directory in /home?

my /home directory currently:

```
4.0K drwxr-xr-x.  9 root root 4.0K Aug  8 10:17 home
```

In there currently all that exists are local user home directories.

**I just noticed a 'local' directory in /home that I hadn't noticed before. This is where the home directories are being stored. Thank you to Maden for helping me notice this**

Cheers.

Comment: Do the parent directories exist, too?  With a prefix of `/home`, it should have `/home/likewise-open/DOMAINNETBIOSNAME/` created for dumping user home directories.

Comment: There needs to be a sub 'likewise-open' directory in /home?

my /home directory currently:

4.0K drwxr-xr-x.  9 root root 4.0K Aug  8 10:17 home

In there currently all that exists are local user home directories.

Comment: @Gary Yup - to avoid conflicting with local users.  Not sure when it's supposed to get created, but you can check what the path is set to be - `lwconfig --show HomeDirTemplate`.  Seems like it should try to create on each login - maybe look for interesting log entries?